# Add commas between spaces in each line

Tags: notepad++

I have a file with 30,000 lines that look like such...

```
123456 123 firstname lastname
```

I am trying to make them all look like

```
123456,123,firstname,lastname
```

How would I do that to a large amount of lines in notepad++

Comment: find and replace(?)https://www.launch2success.com/guide/advanced-find-and-replace-in-notepad/

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia think maybe replace \s with , ?

Comment: well it works with just a blank space ` `, `\s` will also consider tab and newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Open your text file

[image]

Step 2: Go to Search > Replace or use *Ctrl+H*

[image]

Step 3: Type (space) in *Find what* and (comma) in *Replace with* box with *Search mode* as normal. Then **Replace All**.

[image]

Step 4: Spaces are replaced with commas. **Save** the changes in your file

[image]

**Note:** Using *\s* with search mode regular expression will replace all tabs, spaces, and EOL (end of a line) with commas and your output will come in a single line.